# Burninate [variables]

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, burninate-request

Can we please burninate the [variables](/questions/tagged/variables) tag?

What is the point in it?

We know that programs have variables!

There is no need for over 15.5K posts to be tagged [variables](/questions/tagged/variables)...

[image]

Comment: For a second there I thought that said "Burninate [vegetables]".

Comment: Ehhh same thing @AlEverett :-P

Comment: What about the sidekick [constants] ?

Comment: @Mat not as bad (only 1K) but still should probably be burninated.

Comment: Its at 15k now, and I can't say i've seen a single enlightening use of the tag.

Answer (score 4):

I agree this should be burninated.

As [Mat pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164148/burninate-variables#comment477966_164148) there's a side-kick [constants](/questions/tagged/constants). However this isn't the only tag playing Robin to [variables](/questions/tagged/variables) Batman.

There are a number of other contenders:

1. The parameters, c5.5k: [param](/questions/tagged/param), [parameters](/questions/tagged/parameters), [params](/questions/tagged/params).
2. The local variables, 212: [local-variables](/questions/tagged/local-variables).
3. The global variables, c1.8k: [global-variables](/questions/tagged/global-variables), [globals](/questions/tagged/globals) ([superglobals](/questions/tagged/superglobals)?).

Comment: `+1` good points on all fronts.

Comment: [superglobals] should probably stay. I wouldn't be against one tag for each of local vars, global vars & function parameters (but at most one each). For things like scoping/lifetime/concurrency questions? Maybe. Not sure. I'll probably disagree with myself on those tomorrow (:

Comment: I was tempted to put in [tag:optional-parameters], [tag:optional-parameters] etc etc @mat but I thought I might disagree with myself tomorrow...

Comment: I would argue the good boundary is if it's reasonable to assume it will be used in every program. So get rid of [tag:variables], [tag:local-variables], and [tag:parameters], but leave the others.