# How does one search for tag names in question titles on meta?

Tags: support, search

On meta we can have question like this: [Burninate [variables]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164148/155556) which contain text `[....]` but when I search for `[...]` in the meta search bar it *assumes* that I am looking for things tagged `...`

How do we search for all questions that contain a tag in the title ** including** the braces without the search system searching for the actual tag?

I tried escaping the `[` and `]` with slashes, but that yeilded no results,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `title:` operator, like in [this search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%5Bvariables%5D):

```
title:[variables]
```

Comment: Hmmm but this search returns nothing: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%5Bvariable

Comment: I assume search considers `[variables]` as one word, and brackets aren't something it stems. If you want direct substring matching, your best bet is probably Data Explorer.

Comment: Ahh, ok then. Annoying that one has to use a database search to do a simple substring search....